# Javascript Code stops working when timeout is added

Tags: javascript, event-handling, timeout, click

I am trying to add a class named *pressed* to an element with class named *w*. This will happen when user clicks on element containing class *w*. I then want to remove the class *press* after delay of 100.So this is the code I have writtten.

(In short: I am trying to add animation with js by adding(and then removing after 100ms) a CSS class *pressed*.)

But this is not working, it's behavior is as follows:

1. When I un-comment this part `setTimeout(foo(this.innerText), 100);` even the `document.querySelector("."+this.innerText).classList.add("pressed");` isn't getting executed.

```
document.querySelector('.w').addEventListener("click",function () {
  document.querySelector("."+this.innerText).classList.add("pressed");
  // setTimeout(foo(this.innerText), 100);
});
function foo(stringclass) {
  document.querySelector("."+stringclass).classList.remove("pressed");
  console.log(stringclass);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Class

```
.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 40px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Please add HTML.

Comment: @Scollier HTML is added.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the problem](https://jsbin.com/cawuqudino/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output). When the line is uncomented, stuff still happens.

Comment: @VLAZ When uncommented, line 2 ```document.querySelector("."+this.innerText).classList.add("pressed");``` is not working(i.e. on the webpage it's not reflecting, even though no error in dev console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout(foo(this.innerText), 100);` executes `foo` immediately. You need to pass the function itself.
I believe you want something closer to
`document.querySelector('.w').addEventListener("click",function (e) { document.querySelector("."+e.target.innerText).classList.add("pressed"); setTimeout(function() {foo(e.target.innerText)}, 100); });`